# R Forecasting Arima with external regressors

Tags: r, regression, training-data, arima, forecast

I am trying to forecast product demand by arima with external regressors. My initial data on the earbud and I am trying to forecast sold_count. I want to include visit_count,favored_count,_basket_count,category_sold,category_brand_sold variables. I put my all code below. My code generates model but forecast function gives error.

```
head(earbud)
   price event_date product_content_id sold_count visit_count favored_count basket_count category_sold category_brand_sold category_visits ty_visits
1:    -1 2019-04-30            6676673          0           0             0            0             2                  -1              -1        -1
2:    -1 2019-05-01            6676673          0           0             0            0             1                  -1              -1        -1
3:    -1 2019-05-02            6676673          0           0             0            0             2                  -1              -1        -1
4:    -1 2019-05-03            6676673          0           0             0            0             3                  -1              -1        -1
5:    -1 2019-05-04            6676673          0           0             0            0             2                  -1              -1        -1
6:    -1 2019-05-05            6676673          0           0             0            0             1                  -1              -1        -1
>
```

```
earbud_xts<-xts(earbud,order.by=dates)

earbud_train_xts<-earbud_xts[index(earbud_xts)>"2019-06-19" & index(earbud_xts)<"2020-03-01"]


earbud_valid_xts<-earbud_xts[index(earbud_xts)>="2020-03-01"]


earbud_train_sold_xts<-as.numeric(earbud_train_xts$sold_count)


earbud_xreg1<-earbud[52:306,5:9]
earbud_xreg2<-earbud[52:392,5:9]

earbud_arima_model<-arima(earbud_train_sold_xts,xreg=earbud_xreg1,  order=c(0,1,3))


earbud_forecast_arima<-forecast(earbud_arima_model,xreg=earbud_xreg2)
```

I got this error on the forecast function. I really stuck on that level, I tried many ways but I couldn't solve the problem.

```
Error in predict.Arima(object, n.ahead = h) : 
  'xreg' and 'newxreg' have different numbers of columns
Ek olarak: Warning message:
In forecast.Arima(earbud_arima_model, xreg = earbud_xreg2, h = 88) :
  xreg not required by this model, ignoring the provided regressors
```

Comment: Could you maybe provide some reproducible example? An option would be `dput(earbud)`.

Comment: Actually, I don`t understand your answer sry but I try dput and output is structure(list(price = c(-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 
-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 
-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, and goes on with numbers

Comment: Try using `Arima()`, not `arima()`. The forecast package works better that way.